# jQuery slide, ir para proximo elemento (número de elementos não é fixo)

Tags: jquery, slide

Eu queria fazer um slideShow fadein/out (#overlayFancy, só aparece quando clicamos num '.wrapperExtraImg', estilo plugin fancybox), o código até agora funciona muito bem mas agora queria que fosse para o next (#right, sendo que #left é o 'prev') e caso não haja viesse outravez para o primeiro, o número de imagens (.wrapperExtraImg) não é fixo tanto pode ter 1 como 300 imagens. Até agora tenho isto mas não sei bem o que fazer a partir daqui:

HTML:

```
<div id="overlayFancy">
   <div class="imgSlide">
      <div id="left"></div>
      <div id="right"></div>
   </div>
</div>

    .......

<div id="projectImgs"><?php
    foreach ($dataBase->selectAllFromAtable($dataBase->getDetails($idDetails)[0]->description) as $extraImg) { ?>
        <div id="<?php echo 'admin/' .$extraImg->extra_image_path; ?>" class="wrapperExtraImg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo 'admin/' .$extraImg->extra_image_path; ?>)"></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.wrapperExtraImg' ,function(){
        var image = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#overlayFancy').stop().animate({
            "opacity":"1"
        }, 500);

        $('.imgSlide').append("<img src="+image+">");
        $('.imgSlide').width($('.imgSlide img').width());
});

$(document).on('click', '#overlayFancy' ,function(){

        $('#overlayFancy').stop().animate({
            "opacity":"0",
        }, 300);
        $('.imgSlide').children('img').remove();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.imgSlide img, #left, #right', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); // PARA QUE O SLIDE (#overlayFancy) NÃO DESAPAREÇA SE CLICARMOS NUM DESTES ELEMENTOS
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o atributo `data` para memorizar dados, o caminho e nome das imagens contem caracteres não permitidos para o atributo `id`. Visto isso, você pode fazer algo assim:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="overlayFancy">
   <div class="imgSlide">
      <div id="prev"></div>
      <div id="next"></div>
   </div>
</div>

    .......

<div id="projectImgs"><?php
    foreach ($dataBase->selectAllFromAtable($dataBase->getDetails($idDetails)[0]->description) as $extraImg) { ?>
        <div data-image="<?php echo 'admin/' .$extraImg->extra_image_path; ?>" class="wrapperExtraImg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo 'admin/' .$extraImg->extra_image_path; ?>)"></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.wrapperExtraImg', function () {
    $("#overlayFancy .imgSlide").append("<img src='" + $(this).data('image') + "' data-index='" + $(this).index() + "'>");
    $('#overlayFancy .imgSlide').width($('#overlayFancy .imgSlide img').width());
    $("#overlayFancy").stop().fadeIn(500);
});


$(document).on('click', '#overlayFancy img, #prev, #next', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', '#overlayFancy', function () {
    $('#overlayFancy').stop().fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).find('img').remove();
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '#prev', function () {
    var index = $('#overlayFancy .imgSlide img').data('index');
    if (index == 0) index = $('.wrapperExtraImg').length;
    index--;
    $('#overlayFancy .imgSlide img').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).data('index', index).attr('src', $('.wrapperExtraImg:eq(' + index + ')').data('image')).fadeIn(500);
    })
});

$(document).on('click', '#next', function () {
    var index = $('#overlayFancy .imgSlide img').data('index');
    index++;
    if (index == $('.wrapperExtraImg').length) index = 0;
    $('#overlayFancy .imgSlide img').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).data('index', index).attr('src', $('.wrapperExtraImg:eq(' + index + ')').data('image')).fadeIn(500);
    })
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/24k338L8/)

Comment: Muito Obrigado é isso mesmo. Aprendi realmente

Comment: Só uma coisa, onde implemento o fadeIn/out?

Comment: @Miguel usei o fadein/fadeout para substituir o animate opacity que na verdade apenas deixa o elemento totalmente transparente, mas ele permanece ativo...

Comment: Sim, mas a passar de uma para outra (#next, #prev) gostaria de fadein/out, tentei implementar mas não deu aqui

Comment: @Miguel Você tem que dar o fadeOut no momento do click, e no complete dele, mudar o src e acionar o fadeIn... editei a resposta e o jsfidle.